# What are the limitations of velocity selective coherent population trapping?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, doppler-effect, cooling

I'm somewhat familiar with limitations of Doppler cooling, particularly with the one photon recoil limit, but what I was curious about was what is the next barrier to cooling approaching absolute zero?  I read that coherent population trapping could reach lower temperatures, into the nanokelvin range, and has the possibility of cooling possibly down to 100 pikokelvins with NASA's cold atom lab.  Does the uncertainty principle interfere with going lower than those temperatures?  What are some other basic limits/problems?